# Modify params to redirect in route in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Is it possible to create a quick redirect rule in routes.rb to support:

From:

```
http://example.com/family/uid-123-child
```

To:

```
http://example.com/family/parent?child=123
```

My current solution is below. Rails does not allow me to parse :id to get the number "123" out of it. Could you help?

```
get "family/:id", to: redirect('/parent?child='.concat('%{id}')), :constraints => { :id => /[A-Za-z0-9_\-:]+\child?/}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a block to `redirect`, which allows you to modify the parameters for the redirection:

```
get "family/:id", to: redirect { |params, request| "/family/parent?child=#{params[:id][/[0-9]+/]}"  }, constraints: { id: /[A-Za-z0-9_\-:]+child?/ }
```

Also see the [Rails documentation on redirection](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection).